# Comparing different column values at different row numbers of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am still new to python and pandas and still trying to learn. Trying to use Pandas for a complex scenario. below is a small sample of my dataframe

```
  In [9]: df
Out[9]:
       TXN_KEY Send_Agent  Pay_Agent        Send_Customer   /
0     13272184  AWD120279  AEU002152  1000000000021979638
1     13272947  ARA030122  AWD120279  1000000000030604143
2     13273453  API185805  API190139  2000000000096483346
3     13273870  ANO080012  API352676  1000000000046574257
4     13274676  AUK359401  API185805  1000000000082052557
5     13274871  ACL000105  ACB020203  1000000000082187111


   Pay_Customer           Send_Time            Pay_Time
0     1000000000081805876 2012-05-22 09:45:00 2012-05-31 02:50:00
1     1000000000021979638 2012-05-31 08:09:00 2012-05-31 09:52:00
2     2000000000241863019 2012-05-30 04:18:00 2012-05-30 23:42:00
3     2000000000080690692 2012-05-31 02:25:00 2012-05-31 21:43:00
4     2000000000096483346 2012-05-31 11:25:00 2012-05-31 11:57:00
5     1000000000301277732 2012-05-31 13:07:00 2012-05-31 17:36:00
```

Send_Customer sends money using a send agent to a Pay_Agent where Pay_Customer is receiving the money.

Any agent can be both a send agent as well as a pay agent.

For all Agents I want to do a count of those customers that are sending money and receiving it within 10 hours.

For instance in the above example:
 Customer 1000000000021979638 is sending money using Agent AWD120279 and in under 10 hours it is receiving money at the same agent AWD120279 .

Same for customer 2000000000096483346 at Agent API185805  .

So the count for both AWD120279  and API185805  is 1 for this scenario.

I cannot get my head wrapped around on how to approach such a scenario. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the dataframe from send side and Pay side and performing inner joins gave me the desired output.